# Boolean function. Calling it and using True or false

Tags: c++, function, boolean

I need help with this function it's true for numbers that are only devided by two numbers (1, and the number itself). This is a test function. So the user get's 3 numbers and has to write if they are "only devided by two". I'm not really sure how to call the function so the user can anwser with "Yes" "No"

```
bool test_prastevil(int prastevilo) {
  int c=0;
  for(int i=1;i<=prastevilo;i++) {
    if(prastevilo%i==0) {
      c++;
    }
  }
  if (c==2) {
    return true;
    //if(stevec==1)re++;}
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW, `if (c == 2) {return true;} else {return false;}` is overcomplicated. You can use `return c == 2;` instead.

Comment: Do you need help with the function or with user input?

Comment: I need help with user input. So if he inputs "yes" and the number 7 is "true" he would get 1 point (let's say n++;). But i'm not sure how to do that. SOrry for the bad worded post. I've already made it that he can write "0"=false and "1" for true. But i want the user to anwser by word.

Comment: "it's true for numbers that are only devided by two numbers (1, and the number itself)" -- These are called [*prime numbers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number).

Comment: You could replace the final `if` statement by `return (c==2);`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This part of the post can be deleted.:)

/*------------------------------------------------

For example the function can be written the following way. I assume that 1 (or -1) satisfies the condition.

```
bool test_prastevil(int prastevilo)
{
    unsigned int value = std::abs( prastevilo );

    unsigned int x = 1; 
    while ( x * x < value && value % x != 0 ) x++;

    return value != 0 && x * x == value;
}
```

------------------------------------------------*/

If you need a function that determine whether a number is prome (that is excluding 1) then you can write

```
bool test_prastevil( int prastevilo )
{
    unsigned int x = std::abs( prastevilo );

    bool prime = ( x == 2 ) || ( x % 2 != 0 && x != 1 );

    for ( unsigned int i = 3; prime && i * i <= x; i += 2 )
    {
        prime = x % i != 0;
    }

    return prime;
}
```

If you do not want to consider signed values then simply define the parameter as `unsigned int`

Comment: Yo. That's what my function already does. I want the user to get a number let's say '7' and he then has a chance to say "yes" or "no" if the number is devided by only 2 numbers. I did so the program allows him to write "0" for false and "1" for true, but i want him to be able to do that in words.!

Comment: @user3617642 In clude header <iomanip> and use std::cout << std::boolalpha <</* ...*/

Comment: Let me post the instructions here, because i'm not sure if i don't understand what you are trying to tell me or the other way around :s, i'm sorry.
"The first function for a given integer returns the logical value, if a number is prime (test its divisors). Make sure that the negative numbers, 0, and 1 are not marked as prime numbers."
" In the main program, the user is shown three times a random number and then inputs an answer each time, if a number is prime." and this is the problem, the main program.

Comment: @user3617642 What is the problem with main? Enter three different numbers and call the function with each number as argument.

Comment: So he get's a random number 7. He has to write, if the number is or isn't a prime number. He writes yes and get's 1 point he writes "no" and get's zero points. I don't know how "yes=true" and "no=false"

Comment: @user3617642  I am sorry but I do not understand what is the problem Use if-else statement.